# Best pattern to write a PHP function that checks on access and returns more then boolean?

Tags: design-patterns, php, prototyping

I'm prototyping behaviour of a new application, and want to write some functions that check on access based on some variable dates.

I just want to write separate functions for that, like "canUserSeeThis()" and "canUserSeeThat()"

In case one of these returns false, I want to display a message, but I want that message to be defined in these functions, but the rendering taking part outside the functions.

What is the best "pattern" to quickly build such a functionality? Should I let the message be in the return value? Should I work with throwing exceptions?

I'm just prototyping, so I don't want to end up defining a complete API system yet.

Comment: You wouldn't really wanna do that. Mixing business logic (at least I suppose whether `canUserSeeThis()` returns `true` or `false` depends on your business logic) and presentation layer will lead to tighter coupling. Keep it separate. Ask your object in presentation layer `canUserSeeThis()` and if it returns `true`, print output to UI.

Answer (score 1):

> In case one of these returns false, I want to display a message, but I
>   want that message to be defined in these functions, but the rendering
>   taking part outside the functions.

I think this is a bad idea. In my application permission checking is done using lightweight `Acl` objects. They contain boolean methods checking for permissions. And this is businesss logic layer.

Message display is done in the UI layer and it is dangerous to mix them up.